# Спецификация протокола Symantec PcAnywhere, существует ли?

Tags: протоколы

Существует ли спецификация (описание, rfc и т.д.) протокола Symantec PcAnywhere в открытом доступе?

Comment: Они же его закрыли больше года назад.

Comment: Закрыли поддержку протокола? Или сделали протокол закрытым и убрали спецификацию?

Comment: вроде бы закрыли сам продукт и поддержку его. Насчет именно протокола — не уверен. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PcAnywhere